# What is an acceptable short term for "days this business will be closed"

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm a developer, and looking for a clean label for a menu item which leads to a calendar where the user can choose certain days where the business will be closed. This will prevent events from being created on these days, as well as show different message on the frontend instead of a generic 'no events found for today'

In an example sentence, such a word would be used as such:

I love my job, but with all the ___________ I don't get enough hours.

The answer does not need to be only one word, A few are acceptable.

Comment: ...... ..closures

Comment: I suppose that would work, huh? Closure is a common term in programming, I suppose it slipped my mind because I think of the word differently. But that is how I remember them labeling schools closed for snow. It'll work. Thanks.

Comment: Please note that requests for naming of variables, database columns, and so forth are off-topic here, as they come down to a matter of opinion. If you're asking for a hypernym, please observe the guidance for [single-word-requests]. As you seem to be new to StackExchange, I strongly recommend you take the site [tour] and review the [help] as well,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the business operator label, perhaps ***downtime*** would do the trick:

> ***[Downtime](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/downtime)***
>
> NOUN
>
> *[mass noun]*
>
> 1. Time during which a machine, especially a computer, is out of action or unavailable for use.
>
>    1.1 North American Time when one is not working or active.
>         *‘everyone needs downtime to unwind’*

For a business operator, this has the advantage of stressing that it's their time off, rather than days they're closed (and thus not earning money).

Another option would be ***suspension***:

> ***[Suspension](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/suspension)***
>
> NOUN
>
> 1. *[mass noun]* The action of suspending someone or something or the
>      condition of being suspended.
>      *‘the suspension of military action’*
>      *‘the investigation led to the suspension of several officers’*

This is more clear that business operations will be suspended for some period of time.

Lastly, ***put on hold*** or just ***on hold*** could work too:

> ***[On Hold](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/on_hold)***
>
> PHRASE
>
> 1. Waiting to be connected while making a telephone call.
>      *‘‘I'll just see if he's free,’ Rachel said, and put me on hold’*
>
>    1.1 Temporarily not being dealt with or pursued.
>         *‘he has had to put his career on hold’*

For a customer-facing page, when the business is not operating, I would think you could be more wordy:  *There are no events scheduled today as the business is taking a break*.  Or *...is closed today*.

Comment: Because the label should specify an action they would perform, perhaps ***Schedule Downtime*** or ***Schedule a Suspension*** or ***Plan a Hold*** would work.

Comment: After reading your answer again, **Schedule Downtime** is growing on me. :-)

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had responded and accepted this yesterday. Thanks for the extensive answer. I think I too like the phrase 'Schedule Downtime', though as @M

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Calendar allows you to set your

- work time.  Hours outside of Start time and End Time are non-work times.
- work week. You check days in your work week. Unchecked days are non-work days.

So instead, you want to select non-work hours and non-work days and have work hours and work days default to those that remain.  Is that right?

Perhaps *non-business*, *inactive* or *unavailable*. E.g. *unavailable hours*, *unavailable days of the week*.

I find that working with the negative of a thing to be more confusing then working with the positive but perhaps you have your reasons.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified... The application already allows the definition of business hours, though not on a daily basis. This really only affects the calendar view's time stretch when looking at an 'agenda' view.

What will be defined here are days that create exceptions to the normal hours of operation (holidays), as our client doesn't like that the application responds the same way when all the events are full for a day and when the business is closed or outside the normal hours of operation.

Comment: Word choices are allowed and it appears that you are looking for text to display to a user as opposed to "Naming, including naming programming variables/classes".  I would say that *Off days* is typically understood to encompass Holidays and Weekends.  *I love my job, but with all the* **off days** *I don't get enough hours.*

Comment: Depending on context, *off hours* also works.

Comment: The OED offers *after hours* as an alternative to *off-hour*.

Comment: Off days works as well, that could work for a label for the date selection itself. Thanks. :)